# Can Unchained Monks using Unarmed Strikes benefit from combining Flurry of Blows and Two-Weapon Fighting?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, class-feature, monk, unchained

I have an Unchained Monk at level 1 with the feat Two-Weapon Fighting. Using a full-round attack action with the Unarmed Strike Feat, do I get 3 attacks? (Main, FoB, TWF)

How would the attack bonus be modified if so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Flurry of Blows*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/monk-unchained/#TOC-Flurry-of-Blows) states:

> At 1st level, a monk can make a flurry of blows as a full-attack action. When making a flurry of blows, the monk can make one additional attack at his highest base attack bonus. This additional attack stacks with the bonus attacks from haste and other similar effects. When using this ability, the monk can make these attacks with any combination of his unarmed strikes and weapons that have the monk special weapon quality. **He takes no penalty for using multiple weapons when making a flurry of blows, but he does not gain any additional attacks beyond what’s already granted by the flurry for doing so.** (He can still gain additional attacks from a high base attack bonus, from this ability, and from haste and similar effects).

I think this quite clearly indicates that there is to be no benefit from the [*Two-Weapon Fighting*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-weapon-fighting-combat-final/) line of feats.

As such, at first level and taking the *Flurry of Blows* action, an Unchained Monk will make two attacks at STR+1 (or DEX+1 if you have the appropriate setup), and the *Two-Weapon Fighting* feat provides no impact.

Comment: I didn’t know if the “similar effects” line at the end had something to do with it. Cool, this frees up a feat!

Comment: Another way of looking at it is FoB is a full round action in itself and you cannot combine it with another full round action (Full Attack)

Comment: [The *Two-Weapon Fighting* rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Two-Weapon-Fighting) indicate that it's just an extra attack made available during a full-attack sequence, so I think the clause in *Flurry of Blows* that prevents additional attacks is the only reason they do not both add an attack.

Comment: So even though the text for flurry removed the full strength bonus (on non unarmed strikes), it is still not possible for a 1/2 str modifier to be applied unless using a flurry with a secondary natural attack?

Comment: All Flurry attacks utilise the full Strength modifier for damage, because Flurry of Blows doesn't say otherwise, and that particular rule is part of the TWF rules, which FoB is decidedly not using. Secondary natural attacks use half Strength because their own rules say they do.